# Regarding CloudBlockblob.putBlock and CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockList

Tags: azure, blob

I am aware that we can use `CloudBlockblob.putBlock` and `CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockList` to upload in chunks but these methods do not have lease id parameter.

For this can i form the httpwebrequest with header `"x-ms-lease-id"` and attach to `CloudBlockblob.putBlock` and `CloudBlockBlob.PutBlockList`

---

Hi Gaurav,I could not big comment to your response hence adding it.

I tried with BlobRequest.PutBlock and Blobrequest.PutBlock with following code:

`for (int idxThread = 0; idxThread < numThreads; idxThread++)
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        KeyValuePair blockIdAndLength;

```
                    while (true)
                    {

                        lock (queue)
                        {
                            if (queue.Count == 0)
                                break;

                            blockIdAndLength = queue.Dequeue();
                        }

                        byte[] buff = new byte[blockIdAndLength.Value];

                        //copying chunks into buff from inputbyte array
                        Array.Copy(buffer, blockIdAndLength.Key * (long)blockIdAndLength.Value, buff, 0, blockIdAndLength.Value);


                        // Upload block.
                        string blockName = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(
                            blockIdAndLength.Key));


                             //string blockIdString = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("BlockId{0}", blockIdAndLength.Key.ToString("0000000"))));


                        /// For small files like 100 KB it works files,for large files like 10 MB,it will end up uploading only 2-3 MB
                        /// //Is there any better way to implement Uploading in chunks and leasing.
                        /// 
                             string url = blob.Uri.ToString();
                             if (blob.ServiceClient.Credentials.NeedsTransformUri)
                             {
                                 url = blob.ServiceClient.Credentials.TransformUri(url);
                             }
                             var req = BlobRequest.Put(new Uri(url), 90, new BlobProperties(), BlobType.BlockBlob, leaseId, 0);
                             using (Stream writer = req.GetRequestStream())
                             {
                                 writer.Write(buff,0,buff.Length);
                             }
                             blob.ServiceClient.Credentials.SignRequest(req);
                             req.GetResponse().Close();                                                           

                    }

                }));

            }
            // Wait for all threads to complete uploading data.
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());`
```

This does not work for multiple chunks..Could you please provide your inputs

Comment: You said that the code works fine for smaller size files but fails for bigger files. 2 questions regarding that - 1. What is the block size? 2. What's the error message you get? Normally what I have seen is that if you launch too many tasks in parallel, you start getting errors especially "Underlying connection closed" errors. You could do 2 things: 1. If you're on good Internet connection, try increasing the block size. 2. Try uploading fewer blocks in parallel (say 4 or so). HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. However take a look at [BlobRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758651.aspx) class in [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.protocol.aspx) namespace. It has [PutBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.protocol.blobrequest.putblock.aspx) and [PutBlockList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.protocol.blobrequest.putblocklist.aspx) functions which allows you to specify LeaseId.

Hope this helps.